# .value is set initially for an input, afterwards it quickly set back to blank

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

I wrote a page that calculates some values. I wanted to use form and then get the value from an input, get the value from another input, and then display the result value in another input when I press a button.

However, when I'm trying to set the value of the input, it displays it a few milliseconds then quickly disappears.

Here is the code I'm interested in.

```
<input id="initialInput" type="text" name="in" />
<button onclick="calcFnc()">Calculate</button>

function calcFnc() {
    document.getElementById("initialInput").value = "test";
}
```

How do I make the value stay ?

EDIT:I figured out why the value disappeared, I put the button inside the form, and for some reason it refreshes the page, but I pretty much figured it out. Should I delete this post?

Comment: can you create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem you're describing: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8mwL0cxt/

Comment: If your `<button>` is inside a `<form>` its going to submit the form causing a page reload, which is why it is getting "reset"

Comment: You want to add `type="button"` attribute to your `button` element (then it won’t submit the form any more.)

Comment: The reason is because the default value of the type attribute of a button is submit.

Comment: Yup, you guys are right, it was inside the form. Thank you guys !

Comment: Sorry my question sucks I've gotten much better since then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will not set `type="button"` then this button will be considered as submit button and your form will submitted when you will click on that button.

```
<button onclick="calcFnc()" type="button">Calculate</button>
```